# Travis configuration for multiple projects inside monorepo

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to understand and make the build and deployment of my projects work.

I have a repo named projects. Inside projects I have several CRA (create react app) projects:

```
/projects/react1
/projects/react2
...
```

In my Travis dashboard I can see my projects repo.

Inside each project I have its own `.travis.yml` (the only thing that changes is the app name). I also have the API KEY in a env variable in Travis.

Example: /projects/react1

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - "node"
sudo: false

branches:
  only:
  - master

cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules

install:
  - npm install

deploy:
  provider: heroku
  skip_cleanup: true
  keep-history: true
  api-key:
    secure: $HEROKU_KEY
  app: path-to-my-project
```

How can I make the build and deployment work in this context of multiple projects inside a single repo? I could make it work in one project inside a repo, but I'm totally stuck here and the tutorials I found didn't help much.